# javascript: working with associated arrays in complex objects

Tags: javascript, object, entity

hi i'm trying to work with parts of associative arrays in complex objects:

```
var data = {
    labels: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'],
    series: [
        [12, 9, 7, 8, 5],
        [2, 1, 3.5, 7, 3],
        [1, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    ]
};
```

> alert('labels:' + data1.lables) show the coma separated values, nice but
>   var labels = data.labels; end up with a undefined
>   var labels = data.labels.concat(); is not a methode, of course

question: what is the correct standard method without additional libs to efficiently copy data.labels and data.series and data.series[0] to theire own object var labels, var series, var serie? something alike ..

```
var labels = data.labels
var series = data.series
var serie = data.series[0]
```

> alert('labels: ' + labels) show "labels: Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday"
>   alert('series: ' + series) show "series: 12,9,7,8,5,2,1,3.5,7,3,1,3,4,5,6"
>   alert('first serie: ' + serie) show "first serie: 12,9,7,8,5"

Comment: Make sure you're not executing anything with typos. In your first code snippet, you have `labels` (note the order of `e` and `l`), but in your first yellow snippet, you are saying `var lables = data.lables` (note that the `e` and `l` are in REVERSE order than your first snippet, meaning you will always get undefined).

Comment: So, can you help me understand your question better? What you have with `var labels = data.labels` and `var series = data.series` and `var serie = data.series[0]` should work.